# Apple Mac Book Pro M1 Chip segmentation Error when using python requests library

Tags: python, docker, python-requests, openssl, apple-m1

### Hardware:

- Apple Mac Book Pro with M1 Chip
- Mac OS BigSur 11.6

### Problem:

Long story short fix!

I started developing in my python module connecting a rest api using the **python requests library** over OAuth1 to interact with.

I was using a docker container to develop locally.

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Python 3.8.x
- openssl 1.1.1f

When I ran a requests.delete command in my code it returned always a segmentation error (**SIGSEGV**).

**Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault**

Comment: I have moved the answer (solution) since SO is a Q&A site. If you want you can post your answer and remove the community answer. For next times you can post the question and answer at the same time before showing it. And then you can accept the answer, if it is your answer then you must wait at least 2 days. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: MacOS ships with a Python and OpenSSL.  Does using a non-Docker virtual environment meet your needs and work around this issue?

Comment: Yes working locally using not a container worked. But with a container not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of debugging and searching for this issue I found that the error occurs in the **ssl library**. And this was the entry point how to solve that issue:

### Troubleshoot:

Updating to the latest **Python Version of 3.9** and using at least **openssl==1.1.1g** version.

Here is the Dockerfile how to update Python and openssl on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt update
# SET PYTHON 3.9 AS DEFAULT PYTHON VERSION ON UBUNTU
RUN apt install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt -y install python3.9
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 1
RUN update-alternatives --config python3
WORKDIR /<your_work_dir>
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN apt install -y pip \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt
# FROM HERE OPENSSL
RUN apt install -y wget
RUN wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz
RUN tar -zxf openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz
WORKDIR /<your_work_dir>/openssl-1.1.1l
RUN ./config
RUN make
RUN make install
RUN mv /usr/bin/openssl ~/tmp
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
RUN ldconfig
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

### Notice:

The error occurs obviously on a docker container ubuntu instance when creating it by a M1 chip. Checking the same code on a Windows created docker container (code with the wrong dependencies) on a Windows machine works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could solve it with your solution.

I was using Docker, Flask, Python and Requests on Mac M1.

sometimes when doing requests to a specific Path i got:

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x0000ffff9c931b40 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 642 in write
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 944 in send
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 975 in sendall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1006 in send
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1046 in _send_output
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1286 in endheaders
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1337 in _send_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1291 in request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387 in _make_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672 in urlopen
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449 in send
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646 in send
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533 in request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60 in request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116 in post
  File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
Segmentation fault
```

To Debug **Segmentation fault** use:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html

https://blog.richard.do/2018/03/18/how-to-debug-segmentation-fault-in-python/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).